# Error passing Tuple as 'To' param in Django EmailMessage

Tags: python, django, email, typeerror

I am getting the following error when trying to send an email message where I give the 'To' parameter a tuple of email addresses.

```
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected
> string, tuple found
```

I have looked at the Django documentation for the [EmailMessage class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) and it indicates this should be fine. Anyone have any suggestions about what could be going wrong?

I construct the EmailMessage object like so:

```
spam = EmailMessage("Some title - %s \"%s\"" % (subject, task.name), message,
                                "%s <%s>" % (user.get_full_name(), user.email), settings.MAIL_LIST)
spam.content_subtype = "html"
spam.send()
```

and

```
settings.MAIL_LIST = ["foo@bar.com", "foo2@bar.com", "foo3@bar.com"]
```

Partial Stack trace:

```
> File "/myClass/Mail.py", line 217, in
> contact_owner
>     spam.send()
> 
>   File
> "/port/python-environments/port_web/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail.py",
> line 281, in send
>     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
> 
>   File
> "/port/python-environments/port_web/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail.py",
> line 185, in send_messages
>     sent = self._send(message)
> 
>   File
> "/port/python-environments/port_web/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail.py",
> line 199, in _send
>     email_message.message().as_string())
> 
>   File
> "/port/python-environments/port_web/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail.py",
> line 253, in message
>     msg['To'] = ', '.join(self.to)
> 
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected
> string, tuple found
```

Comment: The last element of `settings.MAIL_LIST` should be: `"foo3@bar.com"`. You missed the `"`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed in question. Not a problem in actual code.

Comment: The error is clear. `self.to` is a tuple. Can you paste the output of `print self.to`?

Comment: @AA: that's not correct. first element of `self.to` is a tuple. @Andrew: do you have a comma after your `settings.MAIL_LIST` definition?

Comment: No I don't have a comma after the MAIL_LIST definition. Should I?

Comment: no. before calling `spam.send`, check what is in `spam.to`.

Comment: When I check spam.to the value is that of MAIL_LIST shown above.

Comment: does the `type(smap.to)` also says that it's a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a non-question because my information above is actually incorrect. My error was pretty much what the error message describes. I was passing a list of string email addresses into code wanting a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Send HTML email example

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

subject = render_to_string('cart/email/order_subject.txt',c)
html_body = t.render(Context(c))
text_body = strip_tags(html_body)

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_body, None, sc.settings['email_order'].split(','))
msg.attach_alternative(html_body, "text/html")
msg.send()
```